# syntax error ternary operator in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, erb

I have one link in view

```
<%= @entry.user.present? ? link_to @entry.user.nickname , account_path(:user_id=>@entry.user,:key=>"check" ) ,:"data-ajax" => false : "user"  %>
```

I wrote the above but i am getting syntax error

Please help me solve it.

Thank you

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: can you paste the error here

Comment: Perhaps the link_to method is confusing the ternary? try adding ( ) to the method call? just a thought...

Comment: oops. so change the call to link_to to look like `link_to(...)` Occasionally I've seen ruby get confused in certain situations when the method ()s are excluded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use parenthesis with link_to arguments. Ruby except a `:` but instead he find `@entry.user.nickname`. rewrite your ternary operator like that :

```
boolean_output ? link_to(arguments,arguments) : "something else"
```

Comment: I believe this is the more appropriate answer here, but it's a matter of personal preference I guess

Comment: I will try agin one more time for sure

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= @entry.user.present? ? (link_to @entry.user.nickname, account_path(:user_id=>@entry.user,:key=>"check" ), :"data-ajax" => false) : "123ish" %>
```